# Riddle: What am I? Part 1

Tags: riddle

What runs but never walks,
has a mouth but cannot talk,
has a head but doesn't think
and has a bed but refuses to sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is:

> A river

The reason:

> The river runs, river mouth, river head, and river bed